# IEEE referencing standards

Tags: quotes, reference, format

I'm writing a report and I need to use IEEE referencing standards in my work. I am referencing work as well as directly quoting it, sometimes immediately afterwards for example.

> Put simply, “the number of times that the signal crosses the 0
>   (zero)level reference […] The ZCR should be directly related to the
>   number of times the waveform repeats itself per unit time” [5]. In
>   their study [5], Amado and Filho go on to…

I cite the same reference twice in quick succession. Is this acceptable?

Comment: I believe you'd want to use *ibid.* for the second reference, but style-guide standards are off-topic here.  You may have better luck at writers.stackexchange.com .

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions regarding style guides are off-topic here at ELU.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't necessarily anything wrong with it, but I would try to avoid it as it winds up looking a bit messy.

I would rephrase it slightly to remove the need to footnote the same source twice in immediate succession:

> Amado and Filho put it simply in their study: “the number…per unit time”[5]. They go on to say…

I think this makes it clear that "They go on to say" refers to the previously footnoted study by Amado and Filho.